# Querying Firebase for Location Range

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, firebase

I have a medium-sized Firebase Database with roughly 30,000 location objects, each of which contain fields such as name, hours, and most importantly, latitude / longitude. On the corresponding mobile application (iOS and Android), I have the user's latitude and longitude loaded every time that they open the application. I then want to be able to load all locations that are within the user's specified distance from their latitude and longitude.

This isn't a question of how to calculate range between points on a spherical surface, but more of a question of the "WHERE" equivalent in a no-sql database. How can I quickly check all 30,000 locations in the database to see if two fields are within a specified (circular) range from the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `startAt()`, `endAt()`, `equalTo()`

This way you can filter your data

```java
databaseRerefence.orderByChild(valueToOrderBy).startAt(valueStart).endAt(valueEnd);
```

Comment: Thanks! After doing some reading it appears that you can only order on one child, in my case latitude OR longitude. Is there any intuitive workaround to this other than receiving a list of all points in a latitude range and then doing a longitude check on the client side?

Comment: Hmm you are correct, apparently you can only order by one child, i would have thought you could just add more sorting after first, but nope. I will look around for a bit see if i can find a neat way!

Comment: @AlexKimpel seems like one of the best solutions is to create a joinedkey. Like latLng in your database is a concat of lat_long values, and then you can orderby this value, however i see problems with this as you say you already have a pretty large size DB.